# Linking libpng & using wxWidget

Tags: c++, linker, g++, wxwidgets

I have an hard time linking my program to libpng or libjpeg.
My program is using some third party static libraries :
wxWidget3.0.4, Google V8, latexpp, symengine

The error I get :

> Application built with libpng-1.2.54 but running with libpng 1.6.26

However, I already compiled libpng 1.2.54 and installed it

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep png
libpng16.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16
libpng16.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
libpng16.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
libpng16.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so
```

I get this error whetever I use the linker flags (dynamic linking) -lpng -l:libpng12.so or with static linking

> "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/libpng/lib/x64_linux/libpng12.a}"

Athrough the program seems to link (when both dynamic and static linking or even when no explicit linker flag to libpng) to libpng-1.2.54 anyways.

```
ldd SpicySpice2 | grep png
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f5727228000)
```

I think one of my dependancy (other than wxWidget) force the use of libpng as shared lib but not in an explicit way.
Is it possible ? How to solve that ?

Thank you for your help

Linker command  :
    -L"/home/florian/workspace/SpicySpice2/lib/v8/x64.release/obj" -L"/home/florian/workspace/SpicySpice2/lib/v8/x64.release/obj/third_party/icu" -L"/home/florian/workspace/SpicySpice2/lib/v8/x64.release/obj/src/inspector" -L"/home/florian/workspace/SpicySpice2/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux" -L"/home/florian/workspace/SpicySpice2/lib/symengine/lib/x64_linux" -L"/home/florian/workspace/SpicySpice2/lib/wxMathPlot/lib/x64_linux" -Wl,--start-group -lv8_nosnapshot -lv8_snapshot -lv8_base -lv8_libbase -lv8_external_snapshot -lv8_libplatform -lv8_libsampler -licuuc -licui18n -linspector -Wl,--end-group -lrt -ldl -pthread -L"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux}" -pthread "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0.a}" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_gtk2u_qa-3.0.a}" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_baseu_net-3.0.a}" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_gtk2u_html-3.0.a}" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0.a}" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.a}" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.a}" "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib/wx/lib/x64_linux/libwx_baseu-3.0.a}" -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lSM -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpng -lexpat -lwxregexu-3.0 -lwxtiff-3.0 -lwxjpeg-3.0 -lz -ldl -lm

Comment: What's your full linking command please? Order matters. And what's the actual error (that's not an error)

Comment: I added the linking command. I saw that the only shared library (libwkhtmltox) that I use has libpng-1.2 as shared library dependency. I m trying to reallocate that dependency to a static version of libpng-1.2 with ld --r

Comment: @F.Jean, how did you configured wxWidgets? Please post the complete configure command. Also, what version of libpng is installed on the system? And finally what Linux flavor do you use?